# Django Crispy Forms: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited;

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

When using Django Crispy Forms on a ModelForm I keep getting an Error:
`Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited;`

According to [this](https://bixly.com/blog/awesome-forms-django-crispy-forms/) website I would have to make the form this way:

```
class HotelImageForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        "image",
        "alt_name"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = HotelImage
```

When I make it this way I get the error I mentioned.

However when I put the fields in there, crispy forms does not seem to do much.

```
class HotelImageForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        "image",
        "alt_name"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = HotelImage
        fields = ('image', 'alt_name')
```

I have also added `def __init__` but that did not work either

```
class HotelImageForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(HotelImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.form_tag = False
        helper.layout = Layout(
            "image",
            "alt_name"
        )

    class Meta:
        model = HotelImage
```

This is the code from the view:

```
def hotel_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hotel_form = HotelForm(request.POST, instance=Hotel())
        hotel_image_form = HotelImageForm(request.POST, instance=HotelImage())
        if hotel_form.is_valid():
            new_hotel = hotel_form.save()
            hotel_image = hotel_image_form.save()
            hotel_image.hotel = new_hotel
            employee.save()
            employee.hotel.add(new_hotel)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(hotel_registered))
    else:
        hotel_form = HotelForm(instance=Hotel())
        hotel_image_form = HotelImageForm(instance=HotelImage())

    context = {
        'hotel_form': hotel_form,
        'hotel_image_form': hotel_image_form,
    }
    context.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('hotel/hotel-registration-form.html', context)
```

And the code from the template:

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ hotel_form|crispy }}
        {% crispy hotel_image_form hotel_image_form.helper %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg margin-bottom-20" value="Registreren">
    </div>
```

`hotel_form` does not use Crispy forms in the forms code at the moment.

I hope someone could tell me what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: As the message says, Django requires that you set `fields` or `exclude` for model forms. If the blog post does not do that, it was probably written for an older version of Django. When you add `fields`, what actually happens -- it's not clear what you mean by 'crispy forms does not seem to do much'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Did  you try `fields = '__all__'`

or

Try setting the **render_unmentioned_fields** attribute of the helper to **true** check the doc [here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html). It would look something like this:  `helper.render_unmentioned_fields=True`